# Apache receiving hundreds of requests for various domains

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I have an Apache2 instance that started receiving hundreds of requests/s for some reason, for all sorts of domains that are not hosted here. There is nothing public running on it.

Here's an excerpt of the access.log: https://gist.github.com/d9edfc546ca77d17b1df

Facts of interest:

- bind9 was installed on it for a few days, but is not running anymore
- recently switched to a static IP
- there is a public subdomain (i.e. xxx.domain.com) pointing to the machine
- ports 22, 80, and a few others forwarded from the router

iftop shows many active connections to

```
unn-46-234-119-111.cloudee.eu:64526 
dynamicip-94-181-151-242.pppoe.penza.ertelecom.ru:64219
c-71-228-220-228.hsd1.tn.comcast.net:51688 
89-179-33-252.broadband.corbina.ru:62767
static-98-114-145-42.phlapa.fios.verizon.net:32476
```

and other variations of these, all to ports that are blocked on the router.

nethog shows `PID 0` for those...

```
0     root     ..1:80-46.234.119.111:64063             0.000       0.000 KB/sec
```

Comment: Could you post the IP? Looks like it is set up as a proxy on numerous hosts for some mysterious reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your logs it looks like someone is using your apache server as a proxy and what's troubling is that it looks like you are returning **200 ok** to those proxy requests:

```
46.234.119.111 - - [14/Dec/2011:20:26:53 -0200] "POST http://199.7.177.226/login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 11547
```

Return value is "200" and you served "11547" bytes. You should check your apache config to make sure you aren't configured as an open proxy.

Comment: Oh god.. the only enabled config has `ProxyRequests On` followed by a `ProxyPass` directive. Does that make it an open proxy?

Comment: It's definitely proxying arbitrary requests for me. Turn **ProxyRequests** OFF! It is only used for forward proxies, not reverse proxy (which is what ProxyPass does)

Comment: I disabled mod_proxy, now giving out `500` responses. How long should I expect until requests stop coming in?

Comment: It should be fine if you set `ProxyRequests Off`. I'm sure eventually they'll stop hammering your server but if it starts to proxy for anyone again, expect to start getting hammered again.

Comment: Yeah, it probably started to get visibility when we switched to the fixed IP. Thanks a lot!